# Search from Excel combobox, returing results to userform

Tags: excel, vba, search, vlookup, userform

I'd like search from a combobox on a userform, returning 2 items from 2 different rows. So far I am using a predetermined location set to return the alternate rows.

**My question is about this section:**

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()
    If ComboBox1.Text = Sheet1.Cells(3, 1) Then
        oHousing.Text = Sheet1.Cells(3, 2)
        oMeal.Text = Sheet1.Cells(3, 3)
    End If
End Sub
```

---

**Here is what the pseudocode would do:**

1. User selects item in combobox
2. combobox will search `A1:A99` for item
3. then once item is found it will output `B#` and `C#` (`#` is based on location of `A#`)
4. `B#` is outputted to `oHousing` (textbox)
5. `C#` is outputted to `oMeal` (textbox)

---

**On my sheet I have:**

- `A2:A28` with random text (I used ABC's)
- `B2:B28` are random 3 digit numbers (numeric, eg: 001-999)
- `C2:C28` is Random 3 numbers (numeric, eg: 001-999)

---

**Here's the rest of my code:**

```
'Finds the difference in 2 known dates (returns whole number in textbox)
Private Sub CommandButton1_Click()
    Dim firstDate As Date, secondDate As Date, n As Integer
    firstDate = DateValue(sDate.Text)
    secondDate = DateValue(EDate.Text)
    n = DateDiff("d", firstDate, secondDate) - 0.5
    dTotal.Text = n
End Sub

Private Sub CommandButton2_Click()    'Exit the userform (PerDiem)
    Unload PerDiem
End Sub
```

Thanks to all in advance!

Comment: I don't understand what the random numbers are for.  If you haven't found a solution yet I'd suggest you [edit] your question to provide more specific information like sample data and expected output. For example, `return alternate rows` could mean various things. Also, check out the [tour] (and earn a badge doing so!) as well as tips here: "[ask]" as well as how to create a [mcve].  (...and welcome to Stack Overflow!)

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `Find` function.

If a value is found, you can return the **Row Number** with `Found.Row` and **Column Index** with `Count.Column`

```
Private Sub ComboBox1_Change()

Dim Found As Range
Set Found = Sheet1.Range("A1:A99").Find(ComboBox1.Text, , xlValues, xlWhole)

    If Found Is Nothing Then
        'What do you want to do if your value in CommboBox is not found in the range?
    Else
        oHousing.Text = Sheet1.Cells(Found.Row, 2)
        oMeal.Text = Sheet1.Cells(Found.Row, 3)
    End If

End Sub
```

---

If you are sure that your ComboBox value will always exist in your range (maybe you systematically programmed your ComboBox values this way) you can skip the check and simply use:

```
Dim Found As Range
Set Found = Sheet1.Range("A1:A99").Find(ComboBox1.Text, , xlValues, xlWhole)
    oHousing.Text = Sheet1.Cells(Found.Row, 2)
    oMeal.Text = Sheet1.Cells(Found.Row, 3)
```

---

You can find properties of the `Find` method [here](https://excelmacromastery.com/excel-vba-find/). If you are looking for text, you may need to distinguish between case sensitivity (for your needs, does `THIS` = `this`?). The properties that are currently applied means the function is looking for values (`xlValues`), specifically, looking at the whole value of the cell (`xlWhole`). *I.E.* (`this value` will not match with `this`)